# Write db2 table data to flat file

Tags: db2, cobol, mainframe

I have doubt may be it look like basic ,I need to copy data from db2 table to flat file in cobol .1)Can I use just select query to get data and write( or )use cursor and then write.
2)can i use select/ cursor without where clause.can you pls clarify my doubts

I have used select query to get data without cursor.

Comment: I'd suggest using a cursor so your program code can process one row at a time.  Your SELECT statement doesn't need a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a cursor if you want to fetch multiple rows from a DB2 table in COBOL. Your SQL SELECT does not have to have a WHERE clause. If no WHERE clause is specified the entire table will be accessed via the cursor. For each row accessed you can format and move the data to the output file record and write it. At the end, close the cursor and the file.

You can order the retrieval of the rows using SQL ORDER BY.

Note that you have to allocate enough space for the file.

The task requires familiarity with DB2, JCL and COBOL.

[Example](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/studio-enterprise-edition/studioee60sp2ws2/Studio%20EE%2060%20SP2%20WS2%20Windows=2=Web%20Help%202016%20(MF)=en/BKSPSPCESCS017.html)